# How to modify interface of object property in typescript

Tags: typescript

In typescript I am importing interface like this. but i am getting error as shown in below image.

So suggest me a way to add interface for a property in object.

```
export interface Basket {
  buyer: {
    shipping_is_billing: Boolean;
  };
  ammount: {
    cod_sub_total: string;
    cod_total: string;
    discount: string;
    shipping_discount: string;
    ncod_sub_total: string;
    ncod_total: string;
    original_shipping_charge: string;
    original_total: string;
    shipping_charge: string;
    sub_total: string;
    sur_charge: string;
    tax: string;
    total: string;
    total_weight: string;
    wallet_balance: string;
    wallet_balance_deduction: string;
  };
  state: string;
  checkout_type: string;
  coupons: Array<object>;
  currency: string;
  varient: Array<object>;
  channel_type: string;
  MarketplaceStoreId: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  id: string;
}
```

This is store object where i want to update basket interface.

```
export interface Store {
  loading: Boolean;
  auth: Boolean;
  notification: object;
  basket: Basket;
  allProductAttribute: Array<object>;
  buyerAddress: Array<Address>;
  seletedAddressId: string;
}
```

And  i am getting this error

[Why am i getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyY8U.png)

Comment: More context of how the interfaces are being used is needed. Also show what the actual error is, when you hover over `.state`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218), and make sure you present a [mre] that includes the text of the specific error you're seeing.  Also note, you are using the `Boolean` type [when you almost certainly should use `boolean` instead](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object).